# SQL Count joining table with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I need some help regarding counting the data from.

Here is my query so far:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT COUNT(biodata.Nomor_Induk) as jumData
 FROM biodata 
 INNER JOIN statuspegawai ON biodata.Nomor_Induk = statuspegawai.Nomor_Induk 
 WHERE statuspegawai.bagian='IT' 
 GROUP BY biodata.Nomor_Induk)
```

I have got two tables: `biodata` and `statuspegawai`.

Both of tables have the `Nomor_Induk` column.

Comment: What are you actually trying to count?

Comment: Show definition of your tables please .

Comment: ..and share sample data with sample final result.

Comment: everything solved now . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the code here :** 
-missing table alias !

```
select count(*) FROM (
 SELECT COUNT(biodata.Nomor_Induk) as jumData
 from biodata INNER JOIN  
 statuspegawai 
 ON biodata.Nomor_Induk =  statuspegawai.Nomor_Induk 
 where statuspegawai.bagian='IT' 
 Group By biodata.Nomor_Induk
 ) as Alias1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query needs a subquery table alias:

```
select count(*)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(biodata.Nomor_Induk) as jumData
      from biodata INNER JOIN
           statuspegawai 
           ON biodata.Nomor_Induk = statuspegawai.Nomor_Induk 
      where statuspegawai.bagian = 'IT' 
      Group By biodata.Nomor_Induk
     ) t;
```

You can also express this without a subquery:

```
      select COUNT(distinct biodata.Nomor_Induk) as jumData
      from biodata INNER JOIN
           statuspegawai 
           ON biodata.Nomor_Induk = statuspegawai.Nomor_Induk 
      where statuspegawai.bagian = 'IT';
```

Comment: Thanks it works ! sorry for my bad english :(